# Updating the Address bar Through Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, dojo, github

Still now I knew Its not Possible to change the contents of location bar without changing the page (and Yes I am not talking about #). I've recently noticed github.com. How they are doing that on their site ? they can easily get an event when user clicks on Browser's back or next button. dojo.back also have this feature. But how to change the addressbar with javascript without leaving the page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

- **HTML5's [`pushState()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-history-pushstate) function**. Facebook and Github use this, for example. It allows you to modify the complete URL and fires event handlers when the history state changes. Mozilla has a [good overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries).
- The old variant is to use the **hash** part of the URL (this is what Twitter does). This means that you change `window.location.hash`, monitor it for changes and, based on the value of that hash, load the appropriate content. However, this means that when the user requests, say, http://twitter.com/#!/27c3/status/18331752900591616, only the part before the hash sign is requested form the webserver, everything after the hash is *only* the client's business. This means that the server can not yet decide what content to hand to the client.

Answer (score 2):

try [dojo.hash](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo#hash)

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to on GitHub is the # (hash). When you right click on a line number, it adds the number to your hash.

```
window.location.hash = 'HELLO';
```

Put that in a page to try it out. It's not possible to change `window.location` without the page reloading. The back button stuff is a little trickier, but Dojo is your best bet for that. jQuery doesn't provide this. Dojo has pretty clean code though, so you should be able to reverse engineer their functions (if you chose to include that functionality into your own library).

You'll also notice Google is doing the same with: http://code.google.com/p/digitalxero/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Flocale%2Fde

If you click on folders (left), it changes the hash, and provides different content.

Comment: Nope on github there I see no # (hash). and thats why I am wondering. I see Complete URL Change 'WITHOUT' # when I click on some folder.

Comment: @user - Can you provide a URL. I might be able to help better if I can see the page.